# pyvisa getting incomplete response

Tags: python, pyvisa

I'm controlling a remote instrument via TCP/IP link.  When I telnet to the device, I have no trouble interacting:

```
% telnet 12.34.56.78 5024
Trying 12.34.56.78...
Connected to cpe-12-34-56-78.san.res.rr.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to Keysight's 34972A Switch/Measure Unit
34972A> *IDN?
Agilent Technologies,34972A,MY49002127,1.17-1.10-02-02
34972A> DATA:POINTS?
+0
34972A> 
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

But when I try to get the same interactions from a Python script, it appears to fail to flush the current output or something that results in the previous output being displayed.  For example:

```
% python           
Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:04) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvisa
>>> import time
>>> pyvisa.log_to_screen()
>>> rm=pyvisa.ResourceManager('@py')
2021-03-24 21:24:23,808 - pyvisa - DEBUG - SerialSession was not imported No module named 'serial'.
2021-03-24 21:24:23,809 - pyvisa - DEBUG - USBSession and USBRawSession were not imported No module named 'usb'.
2021-03-24 21:24:23,819 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIPSession was correctly imported.
2021-03-24 21:24:23,830 - pyvisa - DEBUG - GPIBSession was not imported No module named 'gpib'.
2021-03-24 21:24:23,830 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Created library wrapper for py
2021-03-24 21:24:23,831 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Created ResourceManager with session 3068185
>>> device = rm.open_resource("TCPIP::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET")
2021-03-24 21:24:33,555 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - opening ...
2021-03-24 21:24:33,581 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - is open with session 8175711
>>> device.read_termination='\r\n'
>>> device.write_termination='\r\n'
>>> print(device.read(encoding='latin1'))
2021-03-24 21:24:59,497 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - reading 20480 bytes (last status <StatusCode.success_max_count_read: 1073676294>)
ÿûÿûWelcome to Keysight's 34972A Switch/Measure Unit
>>> print(device.query("*IDN?"))
2021-03-24 21:25:08,145 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - reading 20480 bytes (last status <StatusCode.success_max_count_read: 1073676294>)
34972A> *IDN?
>>> print(device.query("DATA:POINTS?"))
2021-03-24 21:25:16,767 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - reading 20480 bytes (last status <StatusCode.success_max_count_read: 1073676294>)
Agilent Technologies,34972A,MY49002127,1.17-1.10-02-02
>>> device.close()
2021-03-24 21:25:23,791 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - closing
2021-03-24 21:25:23,791 - pyvisa - DEBUG - TCPIP0::12.34.56.78::5024::SOCKET - is closed
>>>
```

Notice that `print(device.query("*IDN?"))` responds with `34972A> *IDN?` and `print(device.query("DATA:POINTS?" prints the result of the` "*IDN?"` command.

I have tried all nine combinations of `\n`, '\r', and '\r\n' for `read_termination` and `write_termination`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, though I don't consider it a great solution.

In short, the unit is echoing the command, followed by the response.  So `device.query()` is fetching the echoed command; the response is left in the output buffer until the next read operation.

The workaround is to do an initial read to fetch (and ignore) the echoed command, then a second read to get the result:

```
def query_ignoring_echo(device, command):
    device.write(command)
    echoed = device.read()  # read and ignore echoed command
    return device.read()
```